# Can a web service with an SSL certificate be safely accessed within its intranet?

Tags: web-services, ssl, ip

We have various clients with a web service installed on their server that they can connect locally or externally, right now we issued a Self Signed Certificate, but obviously it has issues since no one can verify this is a valid certificate.

We are thinking to make every client get a domain and then issue a SSL certificate to this domain, this will solve the issue and they will be able to connect safely from outside.
The problem is that they won't be able to connect safely from the intranet since they have to use the local IP.

So is there a way to have a public domain that can be accessed externally and internally?

Comment: Why do they have to use the local IP address? If the router is set up correctly they should be able to use the public IP address or domain name seamlessly from inside.

Comment: Because the router will resolve the domain address as the public IP of the router and then it will be forbidden since we can't connect to the public IP internally because of the [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). And not all my clients allow to enable the loopback.